# How to access the right datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm building a treeview with HierarchicalDataTemplates and would like to have some nodes expaned. The Nodes have a property "IsNodeExpanded" that I'd like to bind the property IsExpanded to.

Where I run into troubles is binding to this property. E.g. this

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
            Value="{Binding DataContext.IsNodeExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

will bind to a property IsNodeExpanded defined on my MainViewModel while this

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
            Value="{Binding IsNodeExpanded}">
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

will have no effect at all because, I guess, the binding has a datacontext problem.

**How can I refer to the right datacontext?**

For completeness, here is my TreeView

```
 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding _questions}">
 <TreeView.Resources>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Question}"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource QuestionConverter}}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
         </StackPanel>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainOption}"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding MainOptions}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                       IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                       Command="{Binding DataContext.ToggleSelectedMetaItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                       CommandParameter="{Binding Path=MetaItemId}" />
         </StackPanel>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

 </TreeView.Resources>
 <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
                 Value="{Binding DataContext.IsNodeExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeView}}">
         </Setter>
     </Style>
 </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

**EDIT:**

```
public class MainOption
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MetaItemId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public MainOption()
    {
        this.IsSelected = true;
    }
}

public class Question
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MainOption> MainOptions { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        MainOptions = new List<MainOption>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share also MainOption and Question classes or  definition of properties at least, pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ItemContainerStyle you should not define relative source when binding to IsNodeExpanded property. if itemssource `_questions` is list of Question, then `{Binding IsNodeExpanded}` binds to `IsNodeExpanded` property of `Question` class. I quess you are missing the property.

here is xaml:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="OptionTemplate" DataType="l:MainOption">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="l:Question" ItemsSource="{Binding MainOptions}"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OptionTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{x:Null}">
            <!-- DataContext of type Question -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsNodeExpanded}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

</TreeView>
```

and C# code:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Questions = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
            .Select(i => new Question
            {
                Name = "Question " + i,
                MainOptions = Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
                    .Select(j => new MainOption {Name = "Option " + i})
                    .ToList()
            })
            .ToList();
    }

    public List<Question> Questions { get; private set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MainOption> MainOptions { get; set; }
    public bool IsNodeExpanded { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        IsNodeExpanded = true;
        MainOptions = new List<MainOption>();
    }
}
```

the point is, that you set Style and ItemTemplate of root items in threeview. In HierarchicalItemTemplate ItemSource is used to generate subitems, ItemContaierStyle affects style of subitems and ItemTemplate affects datatempalte of subitems

Comment: Hi Liero, please see my edits above. "{Binding Path=IsSelected}" has no effect, unfortunatly.

Comment: Hower, Intellisense proposes the list "MainOptions" when I type {Binding DataContext. }..

Comment: you have made quite a few mistakes. give me 5 minute to rewrite it. it'll be faster than to describe it

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort!